# Restore Boot Partition from running ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, boot, bootloader, initramfs

I accidentally wiped the /boot partition of my running Ubuntu 14.04. Is there a way to restore it? My Ubuntu system is encrypted and I am dual booting Windows 7.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can start with this existing question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/130281/how-to-restore-boot-folder

Comment: If I run `sudo grub-install /dev/sda`
I get
`Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: error: attempt to install to encrypted disk without cryptodisk enabled. Set `GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK=1' in file `/etc/default/grub'..`

I reinstalled the kernel earlier already. When running `grub-update` it only find the windows partition: 
`Generating grub configuration file ...
  No volume groups found
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda1
done
`

Comment: Have you done this?
Set GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK=1' in file /etc/default/grub'..

Comment: yes I already did this. Though it had no effect on the error message. I just reinstalled the system and luckily if you choose the same username and password at least the ecryptfs encrypted home dir can be reused without problems

Answer (score 5):

I managed to get past this error by settings `GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK=y`, i.e. `y` instead of `1`, despite what the error message says.

I found this solution [on the ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Grub#Encryption).