# Accidentally removed /bin. How do I restore it?

Tags: command-line, restore

I was working on a directory named `bin`. After I was finished, because of the ownership of `bin` and some files within it I accidentally ran:

```
sudo rm -r /bin
```

Instead of:

```
sudo rm -r bin
```

It seems that my hands used to add a `/` in front of everything I type.

How can I restore my `/bin` directory?

*I want the same files that belong to my Ubuntu, I don't like to copy and paste them from a live disk or another running system.*

Answer (score 193, accepted):

### Is it possible?

Well, most trivial and important utilities are installed in `/bin`, and now you lost access to all of them. In fact, if you reboot, your system will not be able to boot-up anymore.

Anyway, we are going to fix the issue and make `/bin`'s contents as close as is possible to where it was. The only difference would be some symbolic links which we will fix too.

---

### How?

First, we should `chroot` into your broken system, but **with a minor difference**! After that we will get a list of installed packages on your system which have any installed file in `/bin` directory, then we are going to only download the needed packages and extract the necessary files into `/bin`. Then we'll be done.

For example, after `chroot`, we can get a list of packages which have installed files in `/bin` using:

```
dpkg --search /bin | cut -f1 -d: | tr ',' '\n'
```

And we can also use:

```
dpkg --listfiles PACKAGE-NAME | grep "^/bin/" # or awk '$0 ~ "^/bin/
```

to list installed files by these packages in `/bin`.

Then we simply create a list of all packages that are necessary to us, then download them and extract them to `/bin` with something like:

```
xargs apt download < list-packages
dpkg-deb -x PACKAGE .
mv ./bin/* /bin
```

However we must use a script to check all installed packages on our system, because doing it manually is just madness.

So I wrote a script which does everything we need. It finds all necessary packages for us to restore `/bin`, shows us the name of each package and their related files that belongs to `/bin`. Here is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of <code>/bin</code> package list as output by my script]

At the end we choose to reinstall all packages or only download and extract the necessary files to `/bin` (which is the recommended option):

[image: Screenshot of options given by my script]

You can grab [a copy of this script](https://github.com/ravexina/restore-bin) or [download it directly](https://github.com/ravexina/restore-bin/raw/master/restore-bin.sh).

---

### Lets start

#### chroot

Boot your system with a live disk which has same architecture as your installed Ubuntu, open a terminal and get root access:

```
sudo -i
```

Mount your `root` file system (for me it's `/dev/sda1`):

```
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

We will need connectivity to the Internet, so copy `resolv.conf` from live Ubuntu to your mounted root partition:

```
cp /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/resolv.conf
```

Now copy the script to somewhere on the mounted partition, e.g:

```
cp /media/ubuntu/usb/restore-bin.sh /mnt/restore-bin.sh
```

or you can download it using `wget`, etc. like:

```
wget https://git.io/v9fRm -O /mnt/restore-bin.sh
```

Mount other necessary paths:

```
mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
mount -t proc /proc /mnt/proc
```

And here is the **minor difference**: how can we `chroot` to a broken system when there is no `/bin` directory in there? Which shell should we run?

So create a temporary bin directory. e.g: named `bintmp` within your broken system root:

```
mkdir /mnt/bintmp
```

Then bind the live `/bin` into that:

```
mount --bind /bin /mnt/bintmp
```

Chroot into the system while setting the `/bintmp/bash` as your login shell:

```
chroot /mnt /bintmp/bash
```

Export the `/bintmp` as your `PATH` environment variable:

```
export PATH=/bintmp:$PATH
```

Give the script the executable bit:

```
chmod +x restore-bin.sh
```

Run the script:

```
./restore-bin.sh
```

Wait for the search to be completed then answer the question we saw in the screenshot. It will start to restore the `/bin` and we are almost done.

After it's done, use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to get out of `chroot` environment and unmount the mounted paths:

```
umount -R /mnt
```

Reboot the system.

#### Restoring the links within `/bin`

Now almost all of files within `/bin` directory are back, except around 5 symbolic links which are managed by `update-alternatives`.

In your running system, run:

```
sudo update-alternatives --all
```

It asks you some questions; you can simply press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to accept them all.

And now we are done.

Comment: This is, without a doubt, the best answer I've seen on Ask Ubuntu. It's extremely kind of you to go to so much work knowing the OP is in an inconvenient situation.

Comment: Oh wait tl;dr. I should have realized that you did that.

Comment: This is amazing. I love how SE design does not give any hint at all that this is a self-answered question.

Comment: @Hamsteriffic it does: see the rectangle containing answerer's name (signature): it has a darker background, which the posts not by the OP don't. This applies to comments, answers and questions.

Answer (score 30):

If your current system still has a running shell and internet access, this can be done using tools existing elsewhere on the system. I'm assuming you only deleted `/bin`. `/bin` of course has the most convenient utility that you could use in such a situation (busybox), but without that, we'll have to get a little creative.

---

Since you already have a running shell, and since `sudo` is in `/usr/bin`, let's get ourselves a running root shell before we do further damage. But `/bin/bash` and most other shells are gone! Luckily, Linux still has an in-memory copy of the shell you're using. So:

```
sudo /proc/$$/exe
```

Strictly speaking we don't need a root shell for much of what follows. But anyway.

Now, `dpkg` still works, at least for finding which packages have files in `/bin`:

```
dpkg -S /bin
```

We can use `awk` to process it and get the package names, and `xargs` and `apt-get` to download the packages (all in `/usr/bin`). If you have a temporary directory that you can use, `cd` there, because your current directory is going to get a bit messy:

```
dpkg -S /bin | awk -F '[, :]' '{NF--}1' | xargs apt-get download
```

Now, the biggest problem we have is that `/bin/tar` is missing, and without it, `dpkg` can't extract the archives. We can get two-thirds of the way there, because:

1. `.deb` files are actually `ar` archives (again in `/usr/bin`):

   ```
   ar x tar_*.deb
   ```
2. Consisting of two `.tar.*` archives, `data` and `control`:

   ```
   $ echo *.tar.*
   control.tar.gz data.tar.xz
   ```
3. While the gzip utilities are in `/bin`, `unxz` is in `/usr/bin`:

   ```
   unxz data.tar.xz
   ```

Now we have a `data.tar` file without `tar` to extract `tar` from it.

[Python to the rescue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html)! This is where `sudo` is really needed:

```
$ sudo python -c 'import tarfile; tarfile.open("data.tar").extractall("/")'
$ echo /bin/*
/bin/tar
```

*Now* we can use `dpkg` to extract the remaining deb files to get a reasonably complete `/bin`:

```
for i in *.deb; do dpkg-deb -x "$i" /; done
```

However, we should still do a proper installation of the deb files, so that symlinks etc. that would be created by packages are re-created:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall ./*.deb
```

Or:

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```

---

Notes:

1. We can't use Python 2 to directly extract the `data.tar.xz` file, since Python 2 only supports gzip and bzip2 compression. Python 3, however, does support it, so you can use Python 3 directly without `unxz`:

   ```
   sudo python3 -c 'import tarfile; tarfile.open("data.tar.xz").extractall("/")'
   ```
2. After getting back `/bin/tar`, you still need to extract some of the deb files before you can use `apt-get`: the shells, coreutils, etc. Easier to just extract all of them and re-install later.

Comment: I didn't test it, But I almost read it completely, it was awesome, actually I tried to find a copy of bash in memory, I searched a little bit, I didn't found anything intresting and after I saw that tar is not in `/usr/bin`,  I said whatever I go with chroot... Awesome.

Comment: A question, isn't `/proc/$$/exe` a link to `/bin/bash`? how does it work when `/bin` is removed? (It's working, but how), I thought it should be a broken link... that was why I leaved this Idea behind.

Comment: @Ravexina didn't get a complete answer, but: [How does the /proc/<pid>/exe symlink differ from ordinary symlinks?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/197854/70524)

Comment: PATH=/usr/lib/klibc/bin:$PATH will put cat and sh back in your path

Comment: @Joshua And every one of them statically linked! Nice!

Comment: I had deleted my bash directory inside the bin and i followed this answer and it worked like a charm!

Comment: Holy Fork this is awesome. I deleted a directory that I didn't know was symlinked to `/bin` and these instructions worked wonderfully. And very easy to do!

Answer (score 7):

You could *temporarily* put files from a live CD or another system into your `/bin` to make your system usable, then replace them with files from your Ubuntu installation by running `apt-get install --reinstall` for packages which have stuff in `/bin`.

Comment: This is what I would do. The live DVD being the same version number will be almost the same if not exactly the same as current installed. If I had a disc or USB Live version I could compare them and post an answer like yours. This thread is more a theory if OP never deleted /bin in the first place which is a possibility as he wrote the answer the same time as the question in all likelihood. Still very nice thought experiment and excellent writing style.

Comment: I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)

Answer (score 1):

Some additions to [this excellent answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/906675/286528), after I encountered this issue (along with deleting `/boot`, `/etc`, `/lib` and `/lib64`):

- `chroot` requires `/lib` and `/lib64` to be present; otherwise you will get the following error:
  `failed to run command ‘/bin/bash’: No such file or directory`
  I copied these from the LiveCD OS and didn't have any problems restoring. YMMV depending on the packages you have installed on the system
- I cannot edit the answer referenced above, but there is a typo:
  `cp /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/resolv.cof`
  should be
  `cp /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/resolv.conf`
- `/boot` can easily be restored using grub tools. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/130319/286528).
- As [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/906985/286528) recommends, `apt install --reinstall <package>` is a great way to restore missing files in `/bin`, `/lib` and `/lib64`.

  - Some packages that required reinstallation: `libaio1`, `mysql-server`, `openvpn`, `vsftpd`

Note to self:
`rm -rf folder /*` is not the same as `rm -rf folder/*`