# Fix broken server, think due to file permissions, error log info in post

Tags: server, permissions

so i changed file permissions so i could edit config and ini files from the ubuntu gui file explorer (couldn't save them before)  I'm using ubuntu 18.04 with server additions. apache2 php7.2 and so no. I used: sudo chmod a+rwx /path/to/file. Then in the ubuntu file explorer my php.ini files still wouldn't let me save them and I changed the permissions in there after right clicking selecting info and going to the middle tab. This option was ghosted out until i had done the above sudo command.
now im getting a 503 service unavailable error and cant even access the server via its ip. Server didny break until after full system reboot.

here is the error log

```
Apr  6 09:38:36 jserver systemd-resolved[1042]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.

Apr  6 09:38:36 jserver systemd-resolved[1042]: message repeated 2 times: [ Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.]

Apr  6 18:29:38 jserver [3200]: gnome-shell: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.

Apr  6 18:33:47 jserver kernel: [    0.995826] ERST: Error Record Serialization Table (ERST) support is initialized.

Apr  6 18:33:47 jserver kernel: [    1.085209] RAS: Correctable Errors collector initialized.

Apr  6 18:33:47 jserver kernel: [   10.569264] EXT4-fs (sda2): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro

Apr  6 18:33:49 jserver gpu-manager[1483]: Error: can't open /lib/modules/5.3.0-45-generic/updates/dkms

Apr  6 18:33:49 jserver gpu-manager[1483]: Error: can't open /lib/modules/5.3.0-45-generic/updates/dkms

Apr  6 18:33:59 jserver systemd-resolved[1176]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.

Apr  6 18:33:59 jserver systemd-resolved[1176]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.

Apr  6 18:34:01 jserver php-fpm7.2[1822]: [06-Apr-2020 18:34:01] ERROR: [/etc/php/7.2/fpm/php-fpm.conf:110] unknown entry 'upload_max_filesize'

Apr  6 18:34:01 jserver php-fpm7.2[1822]: [06-Apr-2020 18:34:01] ERROR: failed to load configuration file '/etc/php/7.2/fpm/php-fpm.conf'

Apr  6 18:34:01 jserver php-fpm7.2[1822]: [06-Apr-2020 18:34:01] ERROR: FPM initialization failed

Apr  6 18:34:20 jserver gnome-shell[2969]: Error looking up permission: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: No entry for geolocation

Apr  6 18:34:29 jserver /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3450]: #011(WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.

Apr  6 18:34:37 jserver gsd-xsettings[3747]: Failed to get current display configuration state: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Name "org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig" does not exist

Apr  6 18:34:37 jserver gsd-sharing[3737]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit gnome-user-share-webdav.service not loaded.

Apr  6 18:34:37 jserver gsd-sharing[3737]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit rygel.service not loaded.

Apr  6 18:34:37 jserver gsd-sharing[3737]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit gnome-remote-desktop.service not loaded.

Apr  6 18:34:38 jserver gnome-shell[3593]: JS ERROR: Gio.DBusError: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get owner of name 'org.freedesktop.ReserveDevice1.Audio0': no such name#012getUniqueBusNameSync@/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com/util.js:58:20#012traverseBusNames/<@/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com/util.js:82:34

Apr  6 18:34:39 jserver gnome-shell[3593]: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name :1.76 was not provided by any .service files

Apr  6 18:34:39 jserver gnome-shell[3593]: Error looking up permission: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: No entry for geolocation

Apr  6 18:34:39 jserver pulseaudio[3618]: [pulseaudio] bluez5-util.c: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.TimedOut: Failed to activate service 'org.bluez': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
```

if someone could help that would be amazing.

Comment: When you "changed file permissions," what exactly did you do? And how exactly did you repair it at the time once your chages were complete?

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux server have you installed and which release number? Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: Hello, please look at [Accidentally removed /bin. How do I restore it?](https://askubuntu.com/q/906674/566421) I think in all possible scenarios you lull need physical access to recover this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I'm using ubuntu 18.04 with server additions. apache2 php7.2 and so no. I used: sudo chmod a+rwx /path/to/file.  Then in the ubuntu file explorer my php.ini files still wouldn't let me save them and I changed the permissions in there after right clicking selecting info and going to the middle tab. This option was ghosted out until i had done the above sudo command.

Comment: Also... the server didnt "break" until i rebooted the system.

Comment: What files did you change permission on ? Start by changing them back to the original permissions. The solution to not being able to modify system files is NEVER to change their permissions.