# Ubuntu 22.04 after "rm /*" symlink /bin is gone, bash complain: /bin/bash: bad interpreter

Tags: command-line, bash, 22.04, rm

Mistakenly ran `rm /*` as `root`.

In result, it did remove all files from linux root dir, but preserved folders. (which is good news)

```
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    7 Aug  5  2020 bin -> usr/bin
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    7 Aug  5  2020 lib -> usr/lib
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    9 Aug  5  2020 lib32 -> usr/lib32
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    9 Aug  5  2020 lib64 -> usr/lib64
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   10 Aug  5  2020 libx32 -> usr/libx32
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    8 Aug  5  2020 sbin -> usr/sbin
```

Because in Ubuntu 22.04 /bin is symlink to /usr/bin, it was also removed.
So if i try to run any command via bash, it fails due error:

If i will try to use /usr/bin/bash, it fails:

```
# /usr/bin/bash
bash: /usr/bin/bash: No such file or directory
```

But file does exist:

```
/usr/bin/bash/
bash: /usr/bin/bash/: Not a directory

# /usr/bin/bas
base32    base64    basename  basenc    bash      bashbug
```

It seems, that main issue is that current bash tries to run use `/bin/bash` in order to run commands:

```
# ldd ls
bash: /usr/bin/ldd: /bin/bash: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

It seems, that bash tries to execute command via `/bin/bash` interpreter, but fails because this symlink is gone.

Saw answer https://askubuntu.com/a/906692, but fails on first steps:

```
#sudo /proc/$$/exe
bash: /usr/bin/sudo: No such file or directory
```

or

```
/proc/$$/exe
bash: /proc/1872780/exe: No such file or directory
```

Again, due issue with `/bin/bash: bad interpreter`

Is there any way to run command in bash using different interpreter or change interpreter path somehow?

Shebangs doesn't seems to work, or may be i'm using them wrong.

Also, i understand that it's possible to restore using liveCD, but it's remote system, and i can't get to it for another month.

Comment: Use `/use/bin/bash`. And restore the removed symlinks..

Comment: Yeah, added that in edit, sorry.

I did try to do that first, but it also fails

Comment: I wonder if the more fundamental issue is the (presumably also stomped) symlink from `/lib64` to `usr/lib64`? That might mean that none of your executables can find `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`. Does `/usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /usr/bin/bash -c 'echo $0'` work?

Comment: It seems, no `/usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /usr/bin/bash -c 'echo $0'
bash: /usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: No such file or directory
`

Comment: Edit

Actually, it fails because /usr/lib64 is empty:
If i will try to use some different dir:

`# /usr/lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1  /usr/bin/bash -c 'echo $0'
Error loading shared library libtinfo.so.6: No such file or directory (needed by /usr/bin/bash)
Error relocating /usr/bin/bash: __snprintf_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/bin/bash: tputs: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/bin/bash: __vfprintf_chk: symbol not found`

It seems to fails to other errors

Comment: Small fixes to again avoid aliases, and it did work, thank

`# /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2  /usr/bin/bash -c '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /usr/
bin/ls -alh /'
total 1.1G
drwxr-xr-x  19 root root 4.0K May 10 17:30 .
drwxr-xr-x  19 root root 4.0K May 10 17:30 ..
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root 4.0K May  9 06:05 boot
drwxr-xr-x  23 root root 5.3K May 10 16:55 dev`

Comment: Apologies, it never occurred to me that you might be using musl - anyhow, can you get the same trick to work for `/usr/bin/sudo ln` ?

Comment: No, musl is not a problem, here. (i just tried to check first ld binary i found)

Problem was: `/usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` -> `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.31.so`
Where `/lib/` -> `usr/lib`

So, we just need to remove all links and use `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` directly

It's was a great suggestion.
Maybe, you can make it in separate answer, so i can approve it?